# Why does traceroute to a device on my network show just one ip address

Tags: networking, router, traceroute

I have a local network here. I am doing traceroute to another system on the same network.
I was expecting two results.
One is the hit to my router, and then to the other machine. But I see just one result as follows

```
1    13 ms   4 ms  12 ms   nj-PC [192.168.1.110]
```

Why is the information about the router not shown?

1) Does router act as a switch here, or

2) Does it not return the packet if the packet is being forwarded on the same interface? or

3) The packet does not go through the router at all. Once it gets the MAC address of the destination, does it directly send it to the destination? My doubt here is the packet will still go through the router, right? Will it just act as a pass through for these packets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My IP is 182.168.1.4  and when I trace route to that device I get.

```
shiva:ToDoList sparcs$ traceroute shiva
traceroute to shiva.home (192.168.1.4), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  shiva.home (192.168.1.4)  78.566 ms  0.060 ms  0.039 ms
```

There is no hop, or a router that is needed to get to another network as your device is local.

So, its telling you the exact route.

When tracerouting to my iPhone I get

```
shiva:ToDoList sparcs$ traceroute Sparcs
traceroute to 192.168.35.181 (192.168.1.181), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.35.181 (192.168.35.181)  5.129 ms  5.317 ms  5.976 ms
```

Its on the same segment.

Your questions :

Why is the information about the router not shown?

1. *Does router act as a switch here, or*
   **Not relevent, not needed in regards to trace route functional intent**
2. *Does it not return the packet if the packet is being forwarded on the same interface?*
   **No**
3. *The packet does not go through the router at all.*
   **True**
4. *Once it gets the MAC address of the destination, does it directly send it to the destination?*
   **No**
5. *My doubt here is the packet will still go through the router, right?*
   **No**
6. *Will it just act as a pass through for these packets?*
   **No**

Good read: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/iosswrel/ps1831/products_tech_note09186a00800a6057.shtml

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer and especially for answering the questions.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, what happens when you run `traceroute nj-PC` is this:

1. The source host [resolves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution#In_computer_systems) `nj-PC` to an IP address. (won't go into the details of that here)
2. The source host checks its local [routing table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table) for a route to that IP address.
   Example routing table:

   ```
   Destination   Gateway        Genmask         ...
   0.0.0.0       192.168.1.254  0.0.0.0         ...  # default route
   192.168.2.0   192.168.1.253  255.255.255.0   ...  # net route
   192.168.3.23  192.168.1.252  255.255.255.255 ...  # host route
   192.168.1.0   0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0   ...  # directly reachable
   ```
3. If the destination is directly reachable (gateway `0.0.0.0` or `On-link`, depending on your operating system), the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of the destination IP address is resolved via [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) and the packet is sent directly to the destination host (via [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)).
4. If the destination is not directly reachable, the MAC address of the gateway IP address is resolved via ARP and the packet is passed to the the gateway (via Ethernet) who then forwards it according to its own routing tables.
5. The [default route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route) catches all destination addresses that are not reachable either directly or via an explicit host or net route. As before, the MAC address of the (default) gateway is resolved via ARP and the packet is passed to the gateway via Ethernet for further delivery.

In your case both source and destination IP address are in the same subnet, so the destination is directly reachable and the packet is thus delivered directly without router involvement. That's why you see only a single hop in the `traceroute` output.

The router device may still act as a switch here, if it has a built-in switch and both devices are connected to that switch, but that's a different matter and unrelated to [routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing). Switching (Ethernet) takes place in the data link layer (layer 2 of the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)), whereas routing (IP) takes place in the network layer (layer 3).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want or need to do a traceroute to a local device on your network. A router connects networks together so it will connect your `LAN(Local Area Network)` to the `WAN(the internet)` which allows you access to the web. So it is only beneficial for tracing hops from your router to a device somewhere outside of your local network.

It's main goal is for troubleshooting network failures. So the traceroute won't leave your router because the other device is on the same network.

Here is a good article that will show you how it works and how the different OSes handle traceroutes and even some history.

http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/troubleshooting/tools/traceroute/definition.shtml

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of how the traceroute works in general. But I didnt know exactly how it handled the case when it is on the same network.

Comment: My layout is several accesspoints in the house with one central mode/router. Is there any way to 'see' on which accesspoint the device is connected (and not by logging into the AP and checking it there). I was hoping traceroute would return at least my AP ip.